# In Girl Genius, is it possible to slaver-wasp a Jägermonster?

Tags: girl-genius

In [Girl Genius](http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20021104#.VlpSk7_1Bj8), one of the weapons of the Other, a universal enemy, is the "slaver wasp".  It makes humans into one of two breeds of revenant, the [shambler](http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20150617#.VlpUAb_1Bj8) and the [aware](http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20040324#.VlpTcr_1Bj8).  One of the technical breakthroughs during "The Clockwork Princess" is the "slaver wasp that works on sparks".

As far as I know this has never been addressed, but do slavers work on post-humans like the [Jägers](http://girlgenius.wikia.com/wiki/J%C3%A4germonster)?  They were human, but were substantially modified so as to be near-immortal and super-strong.  Their physiology, including their neurophysiology, is substantially modified.

Answer (score 8):

For the specific case of the Jagers, [on this page when Klaus is discussing the re-emergence of the Other with Bang at the beginning of Vol. 6](http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20060327), it appears that they can't be affected by slaver wasps.  At least, as far as the Wulfenbach empire knows.  To my knowledge it hasn't been put to the test, although Klaus seemed to have no problem with them taking point when the Hive Engine was activated back in Volume 3.

This doesn't appear to apply across the board to all sufficiently inhuman constructs however.  The revenant that activated the Hive Engine, Mr. Rovainen, certainly doesn't appear to be fully human.  The extent to which the slaver wasps work, and why not on Jagers, is not dived into in full detail; the Other, so far, has managed to elude major questions like this.